# Angular 16 Encounter problems: Unexpected value 'TranslationModule' imported by the module 'SharedModule'. Please add an @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular, angular16

I encountered this problem after upgrading the angular version. The version using angular-l10n is v8.1.2,
my typescript version is v4.9.5

```
import { TranslationModule } from 'angular-l10n';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        MaterialModule,
        TranslationModule,
        RouterModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        FlexLayoutModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatSelectModule,
        CustomBreakpointsModule,
        PdfViewerModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        ...components.allComponents,
        ...directives.allDirectives,
        ...pipes.allPipes,
        ...uiElements.allComponents,
        ...allShell,
        EventsHandlerDirective
    ],
    exports: [
        CommonModule,
        MaterialModule,
        TranslationModule,
        FlexLayoutModule,
        ...components.allComponents,
        ...directives.allDirectives,
        ...pipes.allPipes,
        ...uiElements.allComponents,
        ...allShell
    ]
})
```

I tried upgrading angular-l10n to version 16, but the changes were too big. Because it is an old project, I really can’t change it.

Comment: And what is your question? or how do u think we can assist u?

Comment: how to solve this error: Unexpected value 'TranslationModule' imported by the module 'SharedModule'. Please add an @NgModule annotation

Answer (score 0):

Angular doesn't recognize your `TranslationModule` as a Module. Maybe you just need to change the name.

I'm not familiar with the package. Try maybe this

```
imports: [
      L10nTranslationModule
  ]
```

Comment: My version is very old and does not have L10nTranslationModule yet.

Comment: As a last resort, I had to upgrade angular-l10n to the latest version